# using 2 bootstrap navbars with different height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd need to use 2 navbars in my web application.

the main navbar with a height that I changed using bootstrap variables:

```
$navbarHeight: 80px;
```

but I need to add an secondary 40px height navbar under that first navbar.

Currently the variable affect both navbars and set them to 80px even if I try changing the CSS style of the secondary navigation bar.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: change the id or class of the second navbar? So that you can style individually, or make a class of navheight and then use in your navbar so <div class= "navbar navheight"> this is just an example, if you post some code of what your using can adjust for your setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `$` infront of your variable I guess you are using Sass.

#### 1. Add an extra class to your navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-small">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. Define the Class via Sass

```
$navbarHeightSmall = 40px; 

.navbar-small{
    .navbar-inner{
        min-height: $navbarHeightSmall;
    }

    &.navbar{
        .brand {
            padding: (($navbarHeightSmall - $baseLineHeight) / 2) 20px (($navbarHeightSmall - $baseLineHeight) / 2);
        }

         .divider-vertical {
            height: $navbarHeightSmall;
        }

       .nav > li > a{
            padding: (($navbarHeightSmall - $baseLineHeight) / 2) 15px (($navbarHeightSmall - $baseLineHeight) / 2);
        }
    } 
}
```

Be sure to include this in your Sass variables scope or redefine the variable: `$baseLineHeight`.

Demo on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/MgcDU/2849/)

Comment: Yes I am using SASS, and your solution looks promising

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Bootstrap the accepted answer is for, but it didn't work for me. This did for Bootstrap 3 (sass):

```
$navbar-height-secondary: 40px
$navbar-padding-vertical-secondary: (($navbar-height-secondary - $line-height-computed) / 2)

.secondary-nav
  &.navbar
    min-height: $navbar-height-secondary
    .nav > li > a
      padding-top: $navbar-padding-vertical-secondary
      padding-bottom: $navbar-padding-vertical-secondary
```

Comment: Bootstrap 2 uses camelCase variable names, Bootstrap 3 does not. So it's normal that example in accepted answer does not work.